# Primefaces scheduler IE 8 month view compatibility

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have not noticed this before. I have an IE 10 and when I run my tests, I put in IE 8 compatibility mode and the problem never exhibited till I tried it from a virtual machine with real IE 8 on it.

The primefaces scheduler does not render properly in month view when viewed in IE 8. I am currently on Primefaces 5.2 community edition. I am not sure what's broken. It looks like it is CSS (I Hope). The problem can be seen when viewing the [[demo page of scheduler]](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/schedule.xhtml)

If anyone has seen this before, can you let me know if there is a fix available or I have to revert back to Primefaces 3.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the component that primefaces uses. It's called full calendar. Here's a commit https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/commit/87cfc4f74361f8368b13c8e647de5c26bcce56ec#diff-08ade688d884f4e51e28a954d5c61932 . This commit talks about the problem. Here's the same bug referenced in primefaces. https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=2428&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Milestone%20Summary%20Stars

So what's the fix. The fix is to use a custom primefaces jar. Since the scheduler.js that needs to be patched for IE8, is part of the jar file. I have untarred the primefaces 5.2 jar and patched the scheduler.js with the bug fix mentioned from the first link.

It seems to be working without issues. So this is for anyone running into this issue. Also you have to change your Maven or whatever build you are using to use the custom 5.2 jar you have created.